# Full Symfony rsync command when deploying production enviroment

Tags: php, deployment, symfony1, rsync

What is the full rsync command run by Symfony when deploying a project with...

```
php symfony project:deploy production --go
```

?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is done via the sfProjectDepoyTask, [see source here](http://trac.symfony-project.org/browser/branches/1.4/lib/task/project/sfProjectDeployTask.class.php). You can browse the source, it's pretty straight forward.

The full command is below. Substitute values between `<` `>`'s with values from you're config.
Some parts of the command are not included depending on your config.

```
rsync --exclude-from=<rsync-dir>/rsync_exclude.txt  --include-from=<rsync-dir>/rsync_include.txt  --files-from=<rsync-dir>/rsync.txt -e ssh -p <port> ./ <user><host>:<dir>
```

You can also see a quick [rsync tutorial here](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/linux-use-rsync-transfer-mirror-files-directories.html).

Answer (score 0):

I've never used it, but looking at the source-code of [**`sfProjectDeployTask.class.php`**](http://trac.symfony-project.org/browser/branches/1.4/lib/task/project/sfProjectDeployTask.class.php), you'll see the `rsync` command is prepared on line [**162**](http://trac.symfony-project.org/browser/branches/1.4/lib/task/project/sfProjectDeployTask.class.php#L162).

A quick'n dirty solution might be to add an `echo` of the `$command` variable.

Else, looking at the source-code of [**`sfFilesystem.class.php`**](http://trac.symfony-project.org/browser/branches/1.4/lib/task/sfFilesystem.class.php), you'll see the [`execute()`](http://trac.symfony-project.org/browser/branches/1.4/lib/task/sfFilesystem.class.php#L285) method first calls this :

```
$this->logSection('exec ', $cmd);
```

So, I suppose there is a way for the command to be loggued somewhere...